# Relation Data with Spring ODBC Driver

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, odbc

I'm trying to insert the the following contents into my messages table:
(title : title, content: this is the content)
I'm using the following code:

```
    package main;



import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;


public class Application {



        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClassName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:odbc:test");
            ds.setUsername("user");
            ds.setPassword("pass");



            JdbcTemplate conn = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

            conn.execute("INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('title','this is the content')");


        }
}
```

This is the exception message:

```
    15:02:09.482 [main] INFO  o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
15:02:09.516 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing SQL statement [INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('title','content')]
15:02:09.530 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
15:02:09.531 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:odbc:test]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:386)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:435)
    at main.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 3 more
```

I've used the following tutorial to do my work:
http://www.javabeat.net/qna/196-spring-framework-working-with-database/

Is it possible that the name of the driver has changed?
I'm sure this question has a 3 word answer.
Thank you.

Comment: what operating system do you use?

Comment: Are you sure server is open?

Comment: @Rembo Windows, wisemann 100%

Comment: Well, since you are using an ODBC driver, did you setup the ODBC data source via the ODBC Admin control panel?

Comment: @Bula Update your question with operating system name and version, what database name and version you trying to connect, what driver jar file you added in your class-path, then it will become easy to answer for anyone.